# Creating Hermetic Maven Builds

Tags: maven, build-automation, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am attempting to create a way in which hermetic builds can be achieved while still relying on SNAPSHOT dependencies in your project.

For the purposes of example, say I have a project which has a dependency structure like this:

```
             ┌ other-1.2-SNAPSHOT
mine-1.2.3 ──┤
             └ thing-3.1-SNAPSHOT ── gizmo-6.1.3-SNAPSHOT
```

What I would like to do is resolve all the SNAPSHOT dependencies locally to something which is related to my current version and then deploy those as releases to my Nexus' release repository. Not all of these dependencies are internal so I cannot simply just make a release on each.

So, in this example, `other-1.2-SNAPSHOT` would become something like `other-1.2-mine-1.2.3` and `thing-3.1-SNAPSHOT` would become `thing-3.1-mine-1.2.3`. This is relatively trivial in about 60 lines of python.

The problem, however, is in resolving transitive SNAPSHOTs to concrete versions. So I also need to convert `gizmo-6.1.3-SNAPSHOT` to `gizmo-6.1.3-mine.1.2.3` and have `thing-3.1-mine-1.2.3` depend on it.

This is only an example of one way in which to achieve what I want. The goal is that in a year or two down the road I can checkout my release branch for version 1.2.3 and be able to run `mvn clean package` or the like without having to worry about resolving long-since-gone SNAPSHOT dependencies.

It's important that this branch be compilable and not just retain all dependencies using something like the `jar-and-dependencies` functionality of the assembly plugin. I'd like to potentially be able to modify the source files and make another release build (e.g., applying a hotfix).

So,

- Is there anything like this available that will be able to convert SNAPSHOT dependencies in a recursive fashion to be concrete?
- Are there any plugins which manage this kind of thing for you? The release plugin had promise with some configuration options on its `branch` goal but it doesn't resolve external deps to the degree that I want.
- Are other techniques available for creating hermetic Maven builds?

Comment: Sounds like an anti Maven hack to me. In Maven, one of basic fundamental rule is **Convention Over Configuration**. If the dependencies are created by yourself, you should manage/use the SNAPSHOT/RELEASE version properly yourself. If they are from somewhere else, you should always use the latest release version (not the SNAPSHOT version). Take a second look in [Maven The Complete Reference - section 3.3.1](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-syntax.html#pom-reationships-sect-versions) and see why SNAPSHOT is used in Maven.

Comment: I very thoroughly understand the fundamentals of Maven. However, I live in the real world with deadlines and third-party libraries who are incredibly useful and yet sit on SNAPSHOT versions for extended periods of time. Jason Van Zyl, somebody you might know, even admits the notion of have a process-heavy system around releases was a huge mistake (and is changing with tesla). Short of maintaining internal forks of all the project we consume, what I'm doing is actually leaps and bounds better than most would.

Comment: well even in the realworld some reason should be taken into account. You are fighting the system here. As you've mentioned Snapshots don't live long enough - even if you are using time-stamped snapshots to rely on for artifact resolution. My approach would be using the dependency and deploy plugins to retrieve all the artifacts and deploy the known snapshot dependencies into the own maven repo by using a script or some self-made-maven plugin. Maybe talking to the other gizmos also helps: if they can release beta versions of their artifacts you can rely on those without a lot of messing around.

Comment: The default maven convention for snapshots/release is very different from the continuous delivery style of build that most teams use (IMO). -SNAPSHOT dependencies and the release plugin simply do not work for many people.  You could say that it's "fighting the system" and "anti-maven" to try and work around this - but I would say that it's working around a design flaw in an otherwise very good tool.

Comment: Please consider my answer. It's a middle ground. Use the snapshots for development and then have a release profile that downloads them to a project-local filesystem Maven repository (yes, it's possible) for the tagged release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a widely used technique, but you can always check your specific SNAPSHOT dependencies into your project as a "project" repository, as described in this blog post: [Maven is to Ant as a Nail Gun is to a Hammer](http://stubbisms.wordpress.com/2008/08/28/maven-is-to-ant-as-a-nail-gun-is-to-hammer-and-nails-you-need-to-move-on/)

In short, use the Dependencies Plugin to create repository *located in your project directory*. The below is copied from the linked blog post (which you should read):

1) Run `mvn -Dmdep.useRepositoryLayout=true -Dmdep.copyPom=true dependency:copy-dependencies`

"This creates /target/dependencies with a repo-like layout of all your projects dependencies"

2) Copy `target/dependencies/` to something like `libs/`

3) Add a repository declaration like the following to your POM:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <releases />
    <id>snapshots-I-need-forever</id>
    <name>snapshots-I-need-forever</name>
    <url>file:///${basedir}/libs</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

You make this an automated part of your build/release process: step 1 by configuring the Dependencies plugin to a lifecycle phasephase, and step 2 using AntRun Plugin to move the downloaded dependencies to the right place..

Hope this works for you. I have to go take a shower now...

Comment: I didn't do this exactly, but future travelers will probably want this solution. I created a special nexus repository and deploy custom versions into it and then update the pom via a script, much like I described in the original post. I used this technique at my last job, however, and it worked brilliantly for a similar use-case.

Answer (score 2):

The maven versions plugin will do most of what you want.

http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/

However you will almost certianly need to run it in a pre-build step in which you resolve all the dependencies and update the pom file accordingly.  Then re-run maven (which re-reads the pom) to run the real build. You might be able to configure everything within the pom itself triggered with a separate goal thus avoiding a separate script.

This works better if you use particular versions instead of SNAPSHOT dependencies and let the pre-build step upgrade them if necessary.  The only real difference for dependency resolution is that maven will always re-download -SNAPSHOT dependencies whereas it will only download normal dependencies if there is a new version available.  However many plugins (including the versions plugin) treat -SNAPSHOT dependencies differently causing problems.  Since every CI build has a new version number I never use -SNAPSHOT, prefering a different tag like -DEV with more predictable behaviour for things like developer local builds etc.

I've spent a lot of time getting maven to do things similar to this. Most maven projects I know have some kind of pre-build step in order to set version numbers or get around other limitations such as this. Trying to do all this in one step usually fails because maven only reads the pom once, string substitution doesn't work in a few places and the deployed/installed pom doesn't generally doesn't contain the results of string substituion or changes made during the build.